# Type inference is lost outside of the pinia store

Tags: pinia, nuxt3

This is my store:

```
export const useMyStore = defineStore('myStore', () => {
    const { data, pending, execute } = useFetch<{id: string, joke:string, status: number}>('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
        immediate: false,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        pick: ['joke']
    });
    return { data, pending, execute }
});
```

Inside the store, the type of data is correctly inferred as:

```
data: globalThis.Ref<{id: string, joke: string, status: number} | null>
```

When using it somwhere else, **the type inference is lost** the type is "any":

[image]

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a bit weird, but:

with the mustache syntax it shows up as "any" without auto-complete:
[image]
[image]

...but when used in a template like this, it shows up as "any", but autocomplete works:

[image]
[image]

Go figure  It might be a Webstorm Problem.